# updatepanel htmlcontrol System.NullReferenceException

Tags: .net, updatepanel

I am confused with this.  I have an updatepanel with file control, two radio buttons, a button named submit, and a button named cancel. When I click the submit button, it throws out System.NullReferenceException (I have set submit button as PostBackTrigger).

The code is shown below.  Line405 is the source of the exception:

```
Line 403:    protected void uploadfile(object sender, EventArgs e)
Line 404:    {
Line 405:        string uploadwhat = Request.QueryString["certificate"].ToString();//identify content of upload
```

aspx code is below:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<div align="center">
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" BackColor="AliceBlue" Height="80px" 
        Width="966px" BackImageUrl="~/catalog/3.png" 
        style="margin-left: 20px" BorderColor="Lime"
        BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px">
 <asp:TableRow>
 <asp:TableCell>
 <asp:Table ID="Table3" runat="server" Width="927px">
 <asp:TableRow></asp:TableRow>
 </asp:Table>
 <asp:Table ID="Table2" runat="server" Width="927px">
 <asp:TableRow></asp:TableRow>
  </asp:Table>
  </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
<asp:Table ID="Table4" runat="server" Width="966px" style="margin-left: 20px">
<asp:TableRow>
<asp:TableCell style="text-align:left"></asp:TableCell>
<asp:TableCell style="text-align:right"></asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div align="center">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:ModalPopupExtender TargetControlID="HiddenField1" PopupDragHandleControlID="panelTitle" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" PopupControlID="Panel1" ID="ModalPopupExtender1"  RepositionMode="RepositionOnWindowResizeAndScroll" DropShadow="true" runat="server"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
 <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
 <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Style="display: none; background-color:snow" ForeColor="Black" Width="600" Height="240">
 <asp:Panel ID="panelTitle" runat="server" style="cursor:move;font-family:Tahoma;padding:2px;" HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#00ccff" ForeColor="White" Height="30" ><b>Upload Certificate or Comment To Review</b>
 </asp:Panel>
 <br />
 <table style="width: 100%;">
 <tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">                         
 <asp:Label ID="CR" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hiid" runat="server" />
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr style="height:15px">
 <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:right">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Certificate<input id="Radio1" type="radio" title="Certificate" name="certificate" value="certificate" checked="checked" onclick="checkawy1()"/>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align:left"> 
                        <input id="File1" type="file" name="upload" style="width:400px" onchange="showimagepreview(this)"/>
                        <img id="imgprvw" alt="uploaded image preview" src="#"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height:15px">
                    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:right">
                         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Justification<input id="Radio2" type="radio" title="Justification" name="certificate" value="justification" onclick="checkawy()"/>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align:left">
                        <textarea id="TextArea1" name="justification" cols="20" rows="2" style="width:400px" disabled="disabled"></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height:15px">
                    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
                        <asp:Button ID="up" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="uploadfile" OnClientClick="return checkcentent()"/>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:Panel>
         <asp:gridview ID="Gridview1" runat="server" Width="932px" DataKeyNames="id"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowEditing = "Gridview1_RowEditing" OnRowDataBound="Gridview1_RowDataBound" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="Gridview1_RowUpdating" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id">
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="hidden" />
        <ItemStyle CssClass="hidden" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CourseName">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="redirect" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CourseName")%>' CommandName="redirect" ToolTip="Download File or Open new dialogue to the source"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseName" HeaderText="CourseName" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="Model">
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" CssClass="hidden" />
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" CssClass="hidden" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Certificate">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="Imagecc" ImageUrl="~/images/certificate.png" runat="server" ToolTip="Click to check your certificate or justification"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Evaluation" DataField="evaluation" ReadOnly="True" >
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comment">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="Imagecm" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/comment.png" ToolTip="Click to check comment" OnClick="Imagecm_Click"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("status") %>' />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("status")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField CancelText="Cancle" EditText="Update Status" HeaderText="Operate" 
            ShowEditButton="True" UpdateText="Update" >
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        </asp:CommandField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Upload">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' ImageUrl="~/images/upload.png" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" ToolTip="Click to upload certificate or justification"/>
                                <%--<asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="编辑" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' OnClick="Button4_Click" />--%>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="comment" HeaderText="CommentContent">
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="hidden" />
        <ItemStyle CssClass="hidden" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="certificate" HeaderText="CertificateContent">
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="hidden" />
        <ItemStyle CssClass="hidden" />
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:gridview>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="up"/>
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you also show the aspx code?

Comment: No one can help me solve the problem ? Emergency case !

Comment: Do you have query string certificate on your URL?

Comment: I have found out the root course and worked it out. But now a new problem came out , I could not upload the file to server, why ?

Comment: What error do you get?